# SQL Server Triggers Order of Execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I was wondering if I might ask a top level SQL Server triggers question - more specifically with regards to the order of processing.

Take the following example: on insert into Table A, I have a trigger that fires and if a condition is met, it updates a given column #1 on the 'just inserted' row of Table A.

Table A also has another trigger that checks for updates to column #1, and if a condition is met, then a new row is inserted into Table B.

Table B also has a trigger set to check on insert and if a certain condition is met, then column #2 is updated in Table A.

Updates to column #2 are also caught in another trigger which can then insert into yet another Table C.

I'm sorry if I have lost you in there... this was not by my design!

I am getting some strange error messages about "Invalid Column names" in triggers totally unrelated to the work process above and I cant help but think that there is simply too much 'triggerness' going on across the same tables for SQL Server to keep up - but I don't know enough about the order of trigger execution and how they might be more tightly controlled to guess.

I am hoping my question is not too vague and can yield some helpful feedback. Most importantly I want to know if the above should 'just work' or are there any specific considerations to make when too'ing and fro'ing triggers to the same table.

Comment: My question is why do you need so many triggers? In nearly 20 years of work with databases I have written maybe 10 or so and probably 6-7 of those I know better ways of handling now.

Comment: I can't answer you question because you did not ask a clear one. But an insert trigger on A that updates A will cause the update trigger on A to execute. The same logic applies to other tables as well. If you are not careful, you will get errors regarding the nesting level. But it sounds you have jumped to conclusions. "Invalid column" errors suggest dynamic sql; I don't see how those errors could be generated by triggers otherwise.

Comment: How could you be updating a row that is just being inserted? That isn't how triggers work in sql server. You would have to have an instead of insert trigger to modify the values that are being inserted. I think you need so share some more details because your whole question hinges off the scenario that isn't possible with the description you provided.

Comment: All very very fair points... I have been using SQL in other jobs for more than 10 years and have always found ways to stay away from Triggers but this new role I have started seem (for some reason) to be mad-keen on them... I think because they are .NET developers and not SQL Developers?!!? This 'mess' is something I have acquired and need to sort out pronto so as much as I would love to have this whole thing re-designed, it is just not feasible at this moment. :( Sob...! I do take note on the 'messing with Table A as it is being inserted' - not a good idea.

Comment: SMor - I couldnt agree with you more!! It took me the best part of a couple of hours to find out what those 'missing column' errors refer to... And it still doesnt make any sense! It was a tenuous last ditch attempt to get a grip on this that lead to my original question to begin with. I will see if I can get some more specific detail in the above question.